# How can I create a React polymorphic component with Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I would like to create a polymorphic button that could actually be a button, an anchor or a router link.

For instance:

```
<Button onClick={e => console.log("click", e)}>A button</Button>

<Button as="a" href="https://somewhere-external.com" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">
  An anchor
</Button>

<Button as={Link} to="/some_page">
  A Link
</Button>
```

I have read many articles, like [this one](https://blog.logrocket.com/build-strongly-typed-polymorphic-components-react-typescript/), but I find the solutions overly complicated, especially when it comes to support `forwardRef`.

I'm looking for something simple to use & easy to understand.

**Edit**: This is for a component library, so I want to avoid any dependency to `<Link>` (provided by react-router or similar libs). Besides, I should be able to support other components, like headless-ui `<Popover.Button>`

I had in mind a solution like below, but the event handlers are all typed against `HTMLButtonElement`, which is obviously wrong.

```
/* Types file */

export type PolymorphicProps<
  OwnProps,
  As extends ElementType,
  DefaultElement extends ElementType
> = OwnProps &
  (
    | (Omit<ComponentProps<As>, "as"> & { as?: As })
    | (Omit<ComponentProps<As>, "as"> & { as: As })
    | (Omit<ComponentProps<DefaultElement>, "as"> & { as?: never })
  )


/* Component file */

const defaultElement = "button"

type OwnProps = {}

type Props<As extends ElementType = typeof defaultElement> = PolymorphicProps<
  OwnProps,
  As,
  typeof defaultElement
>

const Button = <As extends ElementType = typeof defaultElement>(
  { as, children, ...attrs }: Props<As>,
  ref: ForwardedRef<ComponentProps<As>>
) => {
  const Component = as || defaultElement
  return (
    <Component ref={ref} {...attrs}>
      {children}
    </Component>
  )
}

export default forwardRef(Button) as typeof Button
```

Comment: Do you want to achieve this without usage of any library? Or you have any component library you want this to be built on?

Comment: Hi @MalwareMoon, I don't want to use any library, unless it provides only utility types

Answer (score 2):

This is what i came up with:

```
type ValidElement<Props = any> = keyof Pick<HTMLElementTagNameMap, 'a' | 'button'> | ((props: Props) => ReactElement)

function PolyphormicButton <T extends ValidElement>({ as, ...props }: { as: T } & Omit<ComponentPropsWithoutRef<T>, 'as'>): ReactElement;
function PolyphormicButton ({ as, ...props }: { as?: undefined } & ComponentPropsWithoutRef <'button'>): ReactElement;
function PolyphormicButton <T extends ValidElement>({
  as,
  ...props
}: { as?: T } & Omit<ComponentPropsWithoutRef<T>, "as">) {
  const Component = as ?? "button"

  return <Component {...props} />
}
```

### What am i doing here?

- Declare a `ValidElement` type to force the type of `as` to be a valid type, in this case either:

  - A value from `HTMLElementTagNameMap`
  - A general component
- (optional) Declare function overloads to accept or not the `as` parameter while keeping default props
- Declare the function body that renders the corresponding html element with it's props

Of course typescript and tslint are used and only element's own props are viewed.

Usage:

```
const Home = () => {
    const href = "whatever"

    return (
        <PolymorphicButton>just a button</PolymorphicButton>
        <PolymorphicButton as="a" href={href}>an anchor</PolymorphicButton>
        <PolymorphicButton as={Link} to={href}>a Link component</PolymorphicButton>
    )
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but this solution does not support any kind of element. Besides, this is for a component library and I must not have any dependency to the Link component. 
I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: I understood what you're trying to achieve, i'll try something different

Comment: @vcarel I just edited my answer, hope this will fit the requirements

Comment: @Nick into the weeds nit pick: `{ as?: never }` is the same as `{ as?: undefined }` When using `?` the type of the property is unioned with `undefined` so you get `undefined | never`  which reduces to `undefined`. Do both versions work? Sure. But using `never` in this way creates a false impression about what's going on here. `as` could be `undefined`, there is a value we can assign to it, `never` gives the impression that `as` is not assignable with anything on that overload which isn't the case.

Comment: I get a Typescript error on `<Component {...props} />`: Type 'Omit<{ as?: T | undefined; } & Omit<PropsWithoutRef<ComponentProps<T>>, "as">[...]

Props is not used on the first line. Is it intended?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir you're right, i updated my code

Comment: @vcarel i don't get that error and intellisense works as expected, are you using a custom linting library/extension?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir What we really want to say is that `as` should be unset (not `undefined`: unset). It just so happens that `{ as?: undefined | undefined }` and `{ as?: never | undefined }` both simplify to `{ as?: undefined }` but that tells nothing about the intent of the code. Saying that no value for that field is accepted (`never`) is more meaningful, because we never meant to say that the only allowed value for that optional field was `undefined`: we wanted to say that it should not be set and there is no cleaner way to express that in TS than with an optional field.

Comment: @Nick, I think I read too quickly last night and forgot a part of ValidElement's definition. So it works at the end... almost. I have to explicitly pass "a" this way if I want event handlers to be correctly typed:  `<Button<"a"> as="a" onClick={e => console.log(e)}>`. But it's okay to do that.

Many thanks for your solution!

Comment: The solution was missing forwardRef. Since it's a bit tricky, may I update your answer to add it?

Comment: Actually, @Nick, the solution I had in mind does not work with "@headlessui/react" <Menu.Button>
Could you give me some help?

Comment: Do you mean you want to pass `as={Menu.Button}`? I don't use `@headlessui/react` but i can take a look at something in case

Comment: Also, i don't have to pass a generic when using the component, again, are you using an extension/library? it's seems weird to me. I literally wrote this code in a test page of a react project and if i copy-paste it it just works fine as expected :/

Comment: @Nick If you pass an event handler like onClick, is the argument typed as MouseEvent or any ?

Comment: The issue with Menu.Button is when using forwardRef. I can't type it correctly :-/

Comment: if i don't pass the `as` prop and i add the `onClick` event handler i get e as `(parameter) e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>` as expected

Answer (score 0):

```
const Button = (props) => {

const { title, onClick, href, to } = props;
if (href) {
    return (
        <a href={href}>{title}</a>
    )
}
return (
    <Link to={to} onClick={onClick} >{title}</Link>
)
```

}

then we can call it like this
for button

```
<Button 
  title="Click me"
  onClick={()=>{alert("this is button click")})
/>
```

for Anchor

```
<Button 
  title="this is Anchor"
  href="https://www.google.com"
/>
```

for Link

```
<Button 
  title="this is Link"
  to-"/path/subpath"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not a typescript solution.
Also, I would like to support any kind of tag, not only anchors, buttons, react-router Links...

Answer (score 0):

This achieves what you want with all the types intact, except for "fallback to 'button' element" which should be trivial to implement.

```
import { ComponentProps, ComponentType, forwardRef } from "react";

type Tags = keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements;

type Props<T> = T extends Tags
  ? {
      as: T;
    } & JSX.IntrinsicElements[T]
  : T extends ComponentType<any>
  ? {
      as: T;
    } & ComponentProps<T>
  : never;

function ButtonInner<T>({ as, ...rest }: Props<T>, ref: React.ForwardedRef<T>) {
  const Component = as;

  return <Component ref={ref} {...rest} />;
}

const Button = (forwardRef(ButtonInner) as unknown) as <T>(
  props: Props<T>
) => ReturnType<typeof ButtonInner>;

export default Button;
```

You can try it out in the playground: https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-silence-uybwmp?file=/src/App.tsx

I've added a bunch of examples in the `App.tsx`

Comment: Thanks, but this is a variant my solution... where event handlers are not typed correctly. In your codesandbox, you can see that onClick arguments are inferred as "any"

Comment: @vcarel not sure what are you talking about. All the types are correctly resolved in my example. That is specifically what I focused on when creating this solution. Here are screenshots of the `onClick` props on different buttons: https://imgur.com/a/fJkO4Lw

Answer (score 0):

Sure, I have several UI libraries published to a private registry on azure for my org (using TurboRepos). This is a ButtonAnchor Hybrid Component used in multiple codebases that truly segregates ButtonHTMLAttributes from AnchorHTMLAttributes -- but you can extend the logic with additional unions etc to achieve the desired polymorphic component outcome.

There is one definition I'll include before the code from the file for clarity

```
export namespace UI {
  export module Helpers {
    export type Without<T, U> = { [P in Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>]?: never };
   
    /* Provides a truly mutually exclusive type union */
    export type XOR<T, U> = T | U extends object
      ? (Without<T, U> & U) | (Without<U, T> & T)
      : T | U;
  }
}
```

However, for simplicity you can pull those two types out of the Namespace.module.[Type] chaining used in this ui component repo.

```
export type Without<T, U> = { [P in Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>]?: never };

/* Provides a truly mutually exclusive type union */
export type XOR<T, U> = T | U extends object
  ? (Without<T, U> & U) | (Without<U, T> & T)
  : T | U;
```

Here is the file:

```
import type { FC, ButtonHTMLAttributes, AnchorHTMLAttributes, JSXElementConstructor } from "react";
import cn from "clsx";
import LoadingDots from "../LoadingDots";
import UI from "../../typedefs/namespace";

export type ButtonAnchorXOR = UI.Helpers.XOR<"a", "button">;
/**
 * component types allowed by the (Button | Anchor) IntrinsicElements
 */
export type ButtonAnchorComponentType =
  | "button"
  | "a"
  | JSXElementConstructor<
      React.DetailedHTMLProps<
        ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>,
        HTMLButtonElement
      >
    >   | JSXElementConstructor<
    React.DetailedHTMLProps<
      AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>,
      HTMLAnchorElement
    >
  >;;

/**
 * Base props of the (Button | Anchor) components.
 */
export interface ButtonAnchorProps<
  C extends ButtonAnchorComponentType = ButtonAnchorXOR
> {
  href?: string;
  className?: string;
  variant?: "primary" | "secondary" | "ghost" | "violet" | "black" | "white";
  size?: "sm" | "md" | "lg";
  active?: boolean;
  Component?: C;
  width?: string | number;
  loading?: boolean;
}

/**
 * The HTML props allowed by the (Button | Anchor) components.
 * These props depend on the used component type (C = "a" | "button").
 */
export type ButtonAnchorHTMLType<
  C extends ButtonAnchorComponentType = ButtonAnchorXOR
> = C extends "a"
  ? AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>
  : ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>;

export type ButtonAnchorFC<
  C extends ButtonAnchorComponentType = ButtonAnchorXOR
> = FC<ButtonAnchorHTMLType<C> & ButtonAnchorProps<C>>;

export type ButtonType = <C extends ButtonAnchorComponentType = "button">(
  ...args: Parameters<ButtonAnchorFC<C>>
) => ReturnType<ButtonAnchorFC<C>>;

export type AnchorType = <C extends ButtonAnchorComponentType = "a">(
  ...args: Parameters<ButtonAnchorFC<C>>
) => ReturnType<ButtonAnchorFC<C>>;

export type ButtonAnchorConditional<
  T extends ButtonAnchorXOR = ButtonAnchorXOR
> = T extends "a"
  ? AnchorType
  : T extends "button"
  ? ButtonType
  : UI.Helpers.XOR<ButtonType, AnchorType>;

const Button: ButtonAnchorFC<"button"> = props => {
  const {
    width,
    active,
    children,
    variant = "primary",
    Component = "button",
    loading = false,
    style = {},
    disabled,
    size = "md",
    className,
    ...rest
  } = props;

  const variants = {
    primary:
      "text-background bg-success border-success-dark hover:bg-success/90 shadow-[0_5px_10px_rgb(0,68,255,0.12)]",
    ghost: "text-success hover:bg-[rgba(0,68,255,0.06)]",
    secondary:
      "text-accents-5 bg-background border-accents-2 hover:border-foreground hover:text-foreground",
    black:
      "bg-foreground text-background border-foreground hover:bg-background hover:text-foreground",
    white: "bg-background text-foreground border-background hover:bg-accents-1",
    violet: "text-background bg-violet border-violet-dark hover:bg-[#7123be]"
  };

  const sizes = {
    sm: "h-8 leading-3 text-sm px-1.5 py-3",
    md: "h-10 leading-10 text-[15px]",
    lg: "h-12 leading-12 text-[17px]"
  };

  const rootClassName = cn(
    "relative inline-flex items-center justify-center cursor pointer no-underline px-3.5 rounded-md",
    "font-medium outline-0 select-none align-middle whitespace-nowrap",
    "transition-colors ease-in duration-200",
    variant !== "ghost" && "border border-solid",
    variants[variant],
    sizes[size],
    { "cursor-not-allowed": loading },
    className
  );

  return (
    <Component
      aria-pressed={active}
      data-variant={variant}
      className={rootClassName}
      disabled={disabled}
      style={{
        width,
        ...style
      }}
      {...rest}>
      {loading ? (
        <i className='m-0 flex'>
          <LoadingDots />
        </i>
      ) : (
        children
      )}
    </Component>
  );
};

const Anchor: ButtonAnchorFC<"a"> = props => {
  const {
    width,
    active,
    children,
    variant = "primary",
    Component = "a",
    loading = false,
    style = {},
    size = "md",
    className,
    ...rest
  } = props;

  const variants = {
    primary:
      "text-background bg-success border-success-dark hover:bg-success/90 shadow-[0_5px_10px_rgb(0,68,255,0.12)]",
    ghost: "text-success hover:bg-[rgba(0,68,255,0.06)]",
    secondary:
      "text-accents-5 bg-background border-accents-2 hover:border-foreground hover:text-foreground",
    black:
      "bg-foreground text-background border-foreground hover:bg-background hover:text-foreground",
    white: "bg-background text-foreground border-background hover:bg-accents-1",
    violet: "text-background bg-violet border-violet-dark hover:bg-[#7123be]"
  };

  const sizes = {
    sm: "h-8 leading-3 text-sm px-1.5 py-3",
    md: "h-10 leading-10 text-[15px]",
    lg: "h-12 leading-12 text-[17px]"
  };

  const rootClassName = cn(
    "relative inline-flex items-center justify-center cursor pointer no-underline px-3.5 rounded-md",
    "font-medium outline-0 select-none align-middle whitespace-nowrap",
    "transition-colors ease-in duration-200",
    variant !== "ghost" && "border border-solid",
    variants[variant],
    sizes[size],
    { "cursor-not-allowed": loading },
    className
  );

  return (
    <Component
      aria-pressed={active}
      data-variant={variant}
      className={rootClassName}
      style={{
        width,
        ...style
      }}
      {...rest}>
      {loading ? (
        <i className='m-0 flex'>
          <LoadingDots />
        </i>
      ) : (
        children
      )}
    </Component>
  );
};

const PolyMorphicComponent = <T extends ButtonAnchorXOR = ButtonAnchorXOR>({
  props,
  type
}: {
  props?: ButtonAnchorConditional<T>
  type: T;
}) => {
  switch (type) {
    case "a":
      return <Anchor Component="a" {...props as AnchorType} />;
    case "button":
      return <Button Component='button' {...props as ButtonType} />;
    default:
      return <>{`The type property must be set to either "a" or "button"`}</>;
  }
};

Anchor.displayName = "Anchor";
Button.displayName = "Button";

export default PolyMorphicComponent;
```

Comment: Your solution supports only a known list of tags, which is not what I need. I would like to write <Button as={AnyComponent}>