# Create a typescript react component that depending on a prop will render either a button or input?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, conditional-types

I would like to have a react component that depending on an `as` property, which is typed as `'button' | 'input'`, will render either a button or an input.

Example usage of this potential component:

```js
<div>
    <InputOrButton as="input" type="color"></InputOrButton>
    <InputOrButton as="button" type="submit"></InputOrButton>
</div>
```

The important part is that the component should be strongly typed. i.e. - if `props.as==='input'` then `type="submit"` will not compile.

More generally, the types of the rest of the properties for this component depend on the value of `as`. if `as` is `input`, it will allow all (but only) the react built-in `input` properties (`DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>`).

If `as` is `button` it will allow all (but only) the built-in `button` properties (`DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>`)

I am looking for a type-safe solution, meaning no usage of 'as' type assertions.

Here is my failed attempt (well, one of them at least):

```js
import { ButtonHTMLAttributes, DetailedHTMLProps, InputHTMLAttributes } from 'react'

type TagName = 'button' | 'input'
type Detail<T extends TagName> = T extends 'button'
  ? DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>
  : DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>

type Props<T extends TagName> = {
  as: T
} & Detail<T>

export function InputOrButton<T extends 'button' | 'input'>(props: Props<T>) {
  if (props.as === 'input') {
    return <input {...props} />
  } else {
    return <button {...props} />
  }
}
```

And the error i'm getting (on the input component):

```
Type '{ as: T; ref?: LegacyRef<HTMLButtonElement> | undefined; key?: Key | null | undefined; autoFocus?: boolean | undefined; disabled?: boolean | undefined; ... 262 more ...; onTransitionEndCapture?: TransitionEventHandler<...> | undefined; } | { ...; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>'.
  Type '{ as: T; ref?: LegacyRef<HTMLButtonElement> | undefined; key?: Key | null | undefined; autoFocus?: boolean | undefined; disabled?: boolean | undefined; ... 262 more ...; onTransitionEndCapture?: TransitionEventHandler<...> | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>'.
    Type '{ as: T; ref?: LegacyRef<HTMLButtonElement> | undefined; key?: Key | null | undefined; autoFocus?: boolean | undefined; disabled?: boolean | undefined; ... 262 more ...; onTransitionEndCapture?: TransitionEventHandler<...> | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'ClassAttributes<HTMLInputElement>'.
      Types of property 'ref' are incompatible.
        Type 'LegacyRef<HTMLButtonElement> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLInputElement> | undefined'.
          Type '(instance: HTMLButtonElement | null) => void' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLInputElement> | undefined'.
            Type '(instance: HTMLButtonElement | null) => void' is not assignable to type '(instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void'.
              Types of parameters 'instance' and 'instance' are incompatible.
                Type 'HTMLInputElement | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLButtonElement | null'.
                  Type 'HTMLInputElement' is not assignable to type 'HTMLButtonElement' with 'exactOptionalPropertyTypes: true'. Consider adding 'undefined' to the types of the target's properties.
                    Types of property 'labels' are incompatible.
                      Type 'NodeListOf<HTMLLabelElement> | null' is not assignable to type 'NodeListOf<HTMLLabelElement>'.
                        Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'NodeListOf<HTMLLabelElement>'.ts(2322)
```

And the error i'm getting on the button component:

```
Type '{ as: T; ref?: LegacyRef<HTMLButtonElement> | undefined; key?: Key | null | undefined; autoFocus?: boolean | undefined; disabled?: boolean | undefined; ... 262 more ...; onTransitionEndCapture?: TransitionEventHandler<...> | undefined; } | { ...; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>'.
  Type '{ as: T; ref?: LegacyRef<HTMLInputElement> | undefined; key?: Key | null | undefined; accept?: string | undefined; alt?: string | undefined; autoComplete?: string | undefined; ... 282 more ...; onTransitionEndCapture?: TransitionEventHandler<...> | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>'.
    Type '{ as: T; ref?: LegacyRef<HTMLInputElement> | undefined; key?: Key | null | undefined; accept?: string | undefined; alt?: string | undefined; autoComplete?: string | undefined; ... 282 more ...; onTransitionEndCapture?: TransitionEventHandler<...> | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'ClassAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>'.
      Types of property 'ref' are incompatible.
        Type 'LegacyRef<HTMLInputElement> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLButtonElement> | undefined'.
          Type '(instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLButtonElement> | undefined'.
            Type '(instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void' is not assignable to type '(instance: HTMLButtonElement | null) => void'.
              Types of parameters 'instance' and 'instance' are incompatible.
                Type 'HTMLButtonElement | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement | null'.
                  Type 'HTMLButtonElement' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLInputElement': accept, align, alt, autocomplete, and 36 more.ts(2322)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they work properly in outside, but it's indistinguishable inside by `if(props.as === 'input')`, have you tried `<input {...(props as Props<'input'>)}  />` ?.

Comment: yeah you're right, it does work when doing type assertion... but I would really like to have this working without a type assertion.

Comment: OK, this seems to be the reason why the code does not compile. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68897217/types-narrowing-with-generics

Comment: I understand, but as far as I know with my knowledge, type assertion is the only way to solve it. If you find a way to handle it without type assertion, let me know, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered a similar question just yesterday, you can give it a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74687776/17264570). In that context i created a general button that could act either as a button, an anchor or an external component. In you specific case i would probably do something like:

```
type ValidElement<Props = any> = keyof Pick<HTMLElementTagNameMap, 'button' | 'input'>

function InputOrButton <T extends ValidElement>({ as, ...props }: { as: T } & Omit<ComponentPropsWithoutRef<T>, 'as'>): ReactElement;
function InputOrButton ({ as, ...props }: { as?: never } & ComponentPropsWithoutRef <'button'>): ReactElement;
function InputOrButton <T extends ValidElement>({
  as,
  ...props
}: { as?: T } & Omit<ComponentPropsWithoutRef<T>, "as">) {
  const Component = as ?? "button"

  return <Component {...props} />
}
```

And it's usage:

```
<>
    <InputOrButton as="button" {/* button props */} />            // a button
    <InputOrButton as="input" name="myinput" {/*input props*/} /> // an input
</>
```